# Angular JS resolve in a resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I mean by resolve in a resolve is that I want to be able to resolve the user first, and then resolve all his additional info, eg, addressess, contacts, friends.

What I currently have:

```
.state('website', {
            url : '',
            abstract : true,
            resolve : {
                // Request the current signed in user >
                current_user : ['Auth', function(Auth){
                    return Auth.requestUser();
                }]
            },
            views : {
                'main' : {
                    templateUrl : 'template.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

What I'll like to do is the following:

```
.state('website', {
            url : '',
            abstract : true,
            resolve : {
                // Request the current signed in user >
                current_user : ['Auth', function(Auth){
                    Auth.requestUser().then(function(){
                       // HERE I WANT TO RESOLVE OTHER RESOURCES
                       // WHAT WILL I RETURN HERE?
                    });
                }]
            },
            views : {
                'main' : {
                    templateUrl : 'template.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CqtdqqdtkiXQzAgzp6hZ?p=preview see this link for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject "resolved" parameters into other resolve functions:

```
resolve: {
  current_user: ['Auth', function(Auth){
    return Auth.requestUser();
  }],

  // "Svc" here is some service I assume you have to get friends, address, etc...
  friends: ["Svc", "current_user", function(Svc, current_user){
     // Svc.getFriends can return a promise or a value
     return Svc.getFriends(current_user);
  }],

  address: ["Svc", "current_user", function(Svc, current_user){
     return Svc.getAddress(current_user);
  }]
}
```

Then, in the controller for that state, you can inject `current_user`, `friends`, and `address` as parameters:

```
.controller("WebsiteMainViewCtrl", function($scope, current_user, friends, address){
   // ...
})
```

Comment: this one is better and clean

Comment: Perfect, this is pretty neat!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
 resolve : {
       // Request the current signed in user >
       current_user : ['Auth', function(Auth){
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          Auth.requestUser().then(function(){
              // Call this deferred.resolve in inner asyc callback
              deferred.resolve(data);
          });
          return deferred.promise;

       }]
 }
```

Or

You can also use chaining

```
  resolve : {
       // Request the current signed in user >
       current_user : ['Auth', function(Auth, userInformation){
          var authData;
          return Auth
              .requestUser()
              .then(function (_authData) {
                  // do something with dataFromAuth
                  authData = _authData;
                  return userInformation.getDetailInfoAboutUser(_authData.userid); 
              })
              .then(function (detailedUserInfoObject) {
                  // do something with dataFromOtherResource and return
                  detailedUserInfoObject.authInfo = authData;
                  return detailedUserInfoObject;
              });
       }]
 }
```

Comment: While this will fetch all the "other" data, it will also assign `dataFromOtherResouce` to the injectable `current_user`, which seems counter-intuitive

Comment: `OtherResource(dataFromAuth.something);` will return promise. so the last then function will not get called until `OtherResource(dataFromAuth.something);`'s returned promise is not resolved.

Comment: I understand, but then you do `return dataFromOtherResource;` - this will assign `dataFromOtherResource` to the now resolved `current_user`

Comment: But, you can manipulate  `dataFromOtherResource` before returning it. and  if you want use the `dataFromAuth` value inside last function then you can simply store it in a variable in second then function

Comment: Ok, but what if I want both the user *and* the other data - which is what the OP requested? You could definitely return an object with all the data you collected: `{user: dataFromAuth.user, other: dataFromOtherResouce}`, sure... sub-optimal, in my opinion, but works... But modify your answer to show that, since right now it assigns unrelated data to `current_user` parameter

Comment: you can do something like this https://gist.github.com/jigardafda/a035db648166bedae71d#file-gistfile1-js

Comment: Right, that's what I meant in my comment as well ... but then, change your answer to show that. And, unrelated to that, your first alternative is kinda broken - where is `data` coming from?

Comment: dude, see the comment above that `// Call this deferred.resolve in inner asyc callback`, `data` variable used is just a reference to show this is how you can pass data to `resolve` function

Comment: @NewDev would you mind if i add your solution in the list too. its clean and more readable. it might help some other people

Comment: How would that "help some other people" more than having an alternative approach right next to yours? That's why SO allows multiple answers.

Comment: all answers at one place dude