# Angular JS: result of first resolve won't get passed into the second resolve

Tags: angularjs, routes, resolve

I'm losing my mind trying to figure out why the following code produces an Unknown Provider error "geonameProvider <- geoname <- country"

```
var cacRouteViewMod = angular.module('cacRouteViewMod', ['ngRoute', 'cacLib']);

cacRouteViewMod.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
  $routeProvider    
    .when('/countries/:country/capital', {
      templateUrl: 'countries/country.html',
      controller: 'countryDetailCtrl',
      resolve: {
        geoname: ['$route', 'getGeoname', function($route, getGeoname) {
          return getGeoname($route.current.params.country);
        }],
        country: ['getCountry', 'geoname', function(getCountry, geoname) {
          return getCountry(geoname.countryCode);
        }],
        neighbors: ['$route', 'getNeighbors', function($route, getNeighbors) {
          return getNeighbors($route.current.params.country);
        }]
      }
   })
});
```

I've seen some codes where almost identical code is given as a working example. Like this other stackoverflow post ([Angular JS resolve in a resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185897/angular-js-resolve-in-a-resolve)).
And this article (https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c).

Why won't mine work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you are using ngRoute (the native routing module in AngularJS) instead of [ui-routeur](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (the module referred in your articles)

Try using ui-router instead, it should looks like:

```
.state('countries', {
      url: "/countries/:country/capital", 
      templateUrl: 'countries/country.html',
      controller: 'countryDetailCtrl',
      resolve: {
        geoname: ['$route', 'getGeoname', function($route, getGeoname) {
          return getGeoname($route.current.params.country);
        }],
        country: ['getCountry', 'geoname', function(getCountry, geoname) {
          return getCountry(geoname.countryCode);
        }],
        neighbors: ['$route', 'getNeighbors', function($route, getNeighbors) {
          return getNeighbors($route.current.params.country);
        }]

   })
});
```

And inject it as a dependency :

```
var cacRouteViewMod = angular.module('cacRouteViewMod', ['ui-router', 'cacLib']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I included angular-ui-router.js in my html, switched to ui.router dependency, inject $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider, and used $stateProvider.state() syntax. The error doesn't show anymore, but it seems like my url doesn't trigger the 'countries' state or any other state besides the `home` - which contains only url, template, and controller property and no resolve.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out that I needed to use $stateParams instead of $route because of the change. I edited your post and will accept your answer. Thanks again.